Pylance use Django V4 after Upgrading to Django V5
I have a model like this:
class Test(models.Model):
    a = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    b = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                condition=models.Q(a__isnull=False) | models.Q(b__isnull=False),
                name="not_both_null",
            ),
        ]

After migrating to Django V5, VS code is reporting:

However the check constraint has been updated in Django V5:

It feels like Pylance is using "cached" old version somehow.
I have tried following ways:

Update Python and Pylance extensions to the latest.
Restart VS Code/reload window.
Restart Pylance server.
Set 'python.analysis.extraPaths' to my venv.
Reinstall Pylance.

Any other ways I can try?

What is the version of your django-stubs?

Is this a VS Code issue or an upgrade issue with Django? Can you run your code as expected and the issue is just notations in your IDE?

@InSync django-stubs==5.1.1 with mypy==1.13.0, my python version is 3.12.8.

@ViaTech It is a VS Code issue. My code is running all good and the issue is the just warning from Pylance in the IDE.

I have found a temp walkaround, after manually delete the:
~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2024.12.1/dist/bundled/stubs/django-stubs
Then Pylance is picking up the right definition from my venv.
I think this is the pre-bundled version of django-stubs from Microsoft which I might be wrong.
